# How to validate Date and Number in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

How can I validate the date format in AngularJS?

I need to validate a number up to two digits of decimal points, and allow users to add thousand separators.

Comment: Show us what you did till now and where you stuck

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<input type=date />` or `<input type=number />` and the browser is a modern browser than AngularJS will do the validation using the browser.  If you need to support older browsers that don't support those input types, then look at using ng-pattern directive to supply a regex.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input#!